# How to detect user actively logged into Windows desktop?

Tags: node.js, windows, command-line

I have a node.js app running as a Windows service via node-windows.

I need to detect if a user is actively logged in, which user, and if the screen is locked or is on the logon screen.

How can I do this with either node or a windows command?